# Проблема при установки пакета

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, package.json

При попытке установить пакеты через команду `npm install` (да и при любом обращении к `npm` ) выдает ошибку:

> Error: Cannot find module 'semver'.

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:998
  throw err;
  ^
Error: Cannot find module 'semver'
Require stack:
- /usr/share/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js
- /usr/share/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:995:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:841:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js:2:14)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js',
    '/usr/share/npm/bin/npm-cli.js'
  ]
}

Node.js v18.12.1
```

Пробовал переустановить сам пакетный менеджер и `node js` - безрезультатно. Пробовал найти недостающий модуль отдельно, но увы ничего. Может кто-нибудь уже сталкивался с такой проблемой и сможет помочь. Платформа - `Linux Ubuntu 22.04`

---

Comment: Проверьте, куда смотрит ваш npm командой `npm get registry`

Comment: Любое использование команды npm выдает выше изложенную ошибку, в том числе и npm get registry